# Trouble installing Kazam

Tags: package-management, dependencies, pacman

I am using Blackarch which is freshly installed. When I try to install Kazam I get this error:

```
failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?[image]

Comment: What happens when you attempt to upgrade `gst-plugins-{base, good}`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You also haven't shown the command used. On Arch-based distros, this can happen if: a) different repositories than the default ones are used (for example, `testing`), holding packages having different dependencies, or b) AUR packages are used; they can have conflicting dependencies with the official packages, or (rarely) c) there is a bug in the official package.